# How to access state with Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I'm using context API for state management in a React application and I'm looking for a way to access state in a stateless function from my Provider class.

I'm familiar with wrapping the Consumer tags around the JSX inside render() but in this case, I am not returning any JSX

**app.js**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute path='/test' component={test} />
            </Switch>
        </Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  };
};
```

**/context/index.js** (Provider Class)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

class Provider extends Component {

  state ={
    firstName: '',
    lastName:'',
    emailAddress: '',
    password: '',
    signedIn: false,
  };

  render(){
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value = {{
        user: {...this.state},
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  };
};

export default withRouter(Provider);
export const Consumer = AuthContext.Consumer;
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest}) => {
  <Route {...rest} render = {() => (

  /* I NEED TO CHECK IF USER IS SIGNED IN. HOW DO I ACCESS this.state.signedIn from within the Provider class? */

  )} />
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

I'm working on a component that needs authentication before accessing the route but first I need to figure out how to pull the state from the Provider class into PrivateRoute.js

Comment: Here is a better implementation of clear structure of `react context API` [Link to related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870459/how-to-manage-navbar-state-with-usecontext-react-next-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the `PrivateRoute` inside another anonymous function which uses context as a render prop and pass it on to the PrivateRoute though props like

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, context, ...rest}) => {
  return <Route {...rest} render = {() => (

     /* use `context.signedIn` from within the Provider class? */

  )} />
}

export default () => <Consumer>{(context) => <PrivateRoute context={context} />}</Consumer>
```

Or if you are using **v16.8.0 or above of react**, you can make use of `useContext` hook

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, context, ...rest}) => { 
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  return <Route {...rest} render = {() => (

     /* use `context.signedIn` from within the Provider class? */

  )} />
}
```

Comment: Couldn't get your first solution to work. If context.signedIn was false, It redirected to a sign in page with no issues but once I was signed in, there were errors when rendering to my desired component. The console errors I got where along the lines of `The error occured in <Context.Provider>" "Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid --expected a string or a class/function but got undefined. Likely forgot to export your component from the file its defined in or mixed up default and named imports` Your second solution (useContext) works with no issues