# How to update my global context and state

Tags: reactjs

I have a state that I want to make global so that I can use it across multiple different components
and I am trying to do this through using context.

So I have my initial Component which gets the data and sets the global state, the issue I am having is when I try to use this state in the other components it seems to be empty because I believe my `GlobalContext` varibale is not updating so will be empty when the other components try to use the state. I cannot seem to figure out what I am missing to ensure my global state and context are both updated so that I can use them across the different components that require the data as well.

Can anyone figure out where I should update my context as well as my state

Component that gets the data initially:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo, useContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


import { GlobalContext } from "./Store";

function Map() {
  // ------- global state
  const [activities, setActivities] = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);





  useEffect(() => {
    setActivitieData();
    console.log("activities after useEffect", activities)
  }, []);



  const getActivityData = async () => {
    console.log("calling")
    const response = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:8800/api/"
    );

    return response.data;
  };

  const setActivitieData = async () => {
    const activityData = await getActivityData();
    setActivities(activityData);
  
    console.log("Global activities state = ", activities);
    
  };



  return !isLoading ? (
    <>

      <MapComp
        activityData={activities}

      />
    </>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

GlobalStateStore component:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";


const initState = [];


export const GlobalContext = React.createContext();

const Store = ({children}) => {
    const [activities, setActivities] = useState(initState);

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={[activities, setActivities]}>
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
} 

export default Store;
```

component I am trying to use the global state in but is empty:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import { GlobalContext } from "./Store";




function ActivityList() {

    const [activities, setActivities] = useContext(GlobalContext);
    let displayValues;


        displayValues = 
      activities.map((activity) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{activity.name}</p>
            <p>{activity.distance}m</p>
            
          </div>
        );
      })
    
    return (
        <>
        <p>Values</p>
        {displayValues}
        </>
    );
}

export default ActivityList;
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Store>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <AllRoutes />
      </div>
    </Store>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You aren't showing how you use `ActivityList`.

Comment: @AKX what do you mean activity list is just a component right now to display the data it is rendered at a route which can be navigated to through the navbar does that clear it up?

Comment: Have you considered redux? Otherwise if you want state to be global I think the objects should be declared in App.js (or whatever the entry point to your app is) then passed to the components that use or update their values

Comment: What is the `GlobalStateProvider` you import but **don't** use in the `GlobalStateStore` component? And the same with `useGlobalState` hook in the `Map` component?

Comment: @bcstryker redux would be overkill for my application and using props to pass down the component tree would again overcomplicate the apps structure as it would require me to pass it to a wide range of components I have evaluated these ideas and believed context was the best option

Comment: @RubenSmn these where other methods I tried but where wrong I have just forgot to update my imports edited the question with correct imports now

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870459/how-manage-global-state-using-context-api-in-react-js

Comment: @bcstryker not exactly as this question is using reducers I do not have a need for reducers as the state can be overwritten each time I do not need to know about the previous state.

Comment: @AKX would it help if I included exactly the route component where ActivityList is included?

Comment: what I believe I am missing is just properly updating the context

Comment: Have you checked that the data from the api is the data you expect? You could try to update the state with hardcoded data, some array with `name` and `distance` objects

Comment: @RubenSmn yes as the data all works as necessary using local states I just want to follow better practises rather than rewriting the function to update a local state in every component that uses the state. I just want to write once and have globally accessible to all other components which require the state

Answer (score 0):

Here's a barebones single-file version of your code that certainly works.

Since you aren't showing how you're mounting your `<Map />` and `<ActivityList />` components originally, there's not much more I can do to help you with that code, though I will note that it's useless to try and log `activities` in the same function that has just `setActivities`, since `setState` is async (and the function will have captured the earlier `activities` value anyway).

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function getActivityData() {
  console.log("calling");
  await delay(1000);
  return [{ name: "foo", distance: 123 }];
}

function Map() {
  const [, setActivities] = useContext(GlobalContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    getActivityData().then(setActivities);
  }, [setActivities]);
  return <>map</>;
}

const initState = [];

const GlobalContext = React.createContext();

const Store = ({ children }) => {
  const [activities, setActivities] = useState(initState);

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={[activities, setActivities]}>
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};

function ActivityList() {
  const [activities] = useContext(GlobalContext);
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(activities)}</div>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Store>
      <Map />
      <ActivityList />
    </Store>
  );
}
```